# Typescript error when getting prisma data and using to pass into a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prisma

I am using typescript, next.js, react, trpc, and prisma. In a top level component I am calling a trpc function that gets all rows of a table that has a many to many relationship to another table. In the findMany function I am including (joining) the other table. in the top level component (Dashboard) I am successfully getting back the data and mapping over it to render another component (Card). All of this is "working" to show the data and nothing is "breaking" on the client. I do however have a typescript error that is breaking my deploy linting.

The Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5pce.png)

Dashboard Component:

```
import { type NextPage } from "next";
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import CreateNewCard from "~/components/CreateNewCard";
import { api } from "~/utils/api";
import type { Packet } from "./Card";

const Dashboard = (props: { organization_id: string }) => {
  const { data } = api.example.getAllUserPackets.useQuery({
    organization_id: props.organization_id,
  });

  return (
    <div className="min-w-screen flex min-h-screen">
      <div className="w-full">
        <div className="">Dashboard</div>
        <div className="flex flex-grow flex-wrap justify-evenly gap-8">
          <CreateNewCard />
          {!data ? (
            <div>Sorry there seems to be no projects for this organization</div>
          ) : (
            data.map((packet) => {
              //console.log("PACKET: ", packet);
              return <Card packet={packet} key={packet.id} />;
            })
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Card Component:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import { api } from "~/utils/api";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { truncatedName } from "../helper/stringManipulations";

const Card = (props: { packet: Packet }) => {
  const [cardData, setCardData] = useState(props.packet);
  const [isEdittingTitle, toggleIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const {
    id,
    deadline,
    progress_indication,
    tags,
    is_priority_high,
    author_id,
    card_author_name,
  } = cardData;

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    setCardData((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      };
    });
  };

  const { mutate, isLoading: isEditing } = api.example.editCard.useMutation({
    onSuccess: () => {
      // do somthing
    },
    onError: (e) => {
      const errorMessage = e.data?.zodError?.fieldErrors.content;

      if (errorMessage && errorMessage[0]) {
        toast.error(errorMessage[0], {
          duration: 3000,
          position: "top-center",
          // Custom Icon
          icon: "",

          // Change colors of success/error/loading icon
          iconTheme: {
            primary: "#000",
            secondary: "#232323",
          },
        });
      } else {
        toast.error("Failed to post. Sorry, please post again later.", {
          duration: 3000,
          position: "bottom-center",
          // Custom Icon
          icon: "",

          // Change colors of success/error/loading icon
          iconTheme: {
            primary: "#000",
            secondary: "#232323",
          },
        });
      }
    },
  });

  const deselect = () => {
    document.querySelector("p")?.toggleAttribute("focus");
  };

  return (
    <div
      onClick={(e) => {
        isEdittingTitle ? toggleIsEditing(false) : null;
      }}
      className="relative w-80 max-w-full content-end rounded-3xl bg-purple-500 px-8 py-4 text-white subpixel-antialiased shadow-xl hover:translate-y-1 hover:bg-purple-600 hover:shadow-sm"
    >
      <div className="max-w-md">
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          <div className="flex justify-between gap-4">
            <p className="font-bold">{is_priority_high && "High"} Priority</p>
          </div>

          <Link
            href="/packet/project-id"
            className="rounded-lg border px-4 py-2"
          >
            Go To Project
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className="mt-2 flex flex-col">
          {!isEdittingTitle ? (
            <p
              onClick={(e) => {
                toggleIsEditing(!isEdittingTitle);
              }}
              className="edit-input w-full  overflow-visible whitespace-pre-wrap bg-transparent text-[26px] font-bold backdrop:max-h-min"
            >
              {cardData.title}
            </p>
          ) : (
            <textarea
              name="title"
              onFocus={(e) => e.target.select()}
              autoFocus={true}
              value={cardData.title}
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                  mutate({ id, column: "title", content: cardData["title"] });
                  toggleIsEditing(!isEdittingTitle);
                }
              }}
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
                handleChange(e);
              }}
              className="resize-none bg-transparent text-[26px]"
            />
          )}

          <p className="">Created By: {card_author_name}</p>
          <div className="flex flex-row">
            <p className="pr-2 font-bold">Due</p>
            <p className=" ">{deadline?.toDateString()}</p>
          </div>

          <div className="py-6 text-[20px]">
            {!tags ? (
              <div></div>
            ) : (
              tags.map((tag) => {
                return <p key={tag.id}>{tag.tagName}</p>;
              })
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="flex h-full w-full items-end justify-between">
          <div className="w-1/2">
            <p className="text-[20px] ">{progress_indication}</p>
          </div>

          <div className=" flex- flex w-2/6 justify-evenly gap-0 self-end">
            {/* {members.map((member) => {
              return (
                <Link key={member.name} href={`/team/${member.name.trim()}`}>
                  <div
                    className={` -mx-4 flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-evenly gap-0 rounded-full hover:-translate-x-1 hover:-translate-y-1 ${member.color} p-2 text-xl`}
                  >
                    <p className={""}>{truncatedName(member.name)}</p>
                  </div>
                </Link>
              );
            })} */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;

export type Tag = {
  id: number;
  tagName: string;
};

export type Packet = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  author_id: string;
  deadline: Date;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  is_priority_high: boolean;
  progress_indication: string;
  card_author_name: string;
  organization_id: string;
  is_org_admin: boolean;
  tags: Tag[];
};
```

Function in TRPC - finds all "packets" that share the user's "organization id"

```
getAllUserPackets: publicProcedure
  .input(z.object({organization_id: z.string()}))
  .query(async ({ctx, input}) => {

    const data = await ctx.prisma.packet.findMany({where: {organization_id: input.organization_id}, include: {tags: true}} )


    return data
  }),
```

Prisma Models in question

```
model Packet {
  id                  String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt           DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt           DateTime @updatedAt
  card_author_name    String?
  author_id           String
  organization_id     String
  is_org_admin        Boolean? @default(false)
  title               String
  description         String
  project_leader_id   String?
  progress_indication Progress @default(CREATED)
  is_priority_high    Boolean? @default(false)
  deadline            DateTime @default(now())
  tags                Tag[]

  @@index([author_id])
}

model Tag {
  id      String   @id @default(cuid())
  tagName String
  packet  Packet[]
}
```

I have tried adding types (seen at the bottom of Card Component) that reflect the data as-well as made sure that my data in the database that may be required isn't causing an issue by "not being there on the frontend". I gave played around with the Card component and what props it is expecting, and also how the Card JSX is receiving data in the Dashboard component.

My lack of familiarity with typescript and Prisma are the culprit but appreciate any help learning what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not make the types for `prisma.schema` models manually, because Prisma creates them for you automatically or manually with the command `npx prisma generate`.

So to fix your issue you need to remove the already manually defined types from `Card.tsx` and import automatically created types from `@prisma/client`. Since the Prisma Client does not automatically handle relations in your types you need to use the following code to make it work:

```
// Card.tsx

import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

const packetWithTags = Prisma.validator<Prisma.UserArgs>()({
  include: { tags: true },
})

type PacketWithTags = Prisma.UserGetPayload<typeof packetWithTags>
```

- https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12022#issuecomment-1050646465
- https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types#problem-using-variations-of-the-generated-model-type

And then you can use the type `PacketWithTags` for your component props type in `Card.tsx` :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that worked. Not generating my own types from my schema, what a novel idea, haha. I really appreciate the time and knowledge. All the best.